# How to model the rank data

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-modeling, statsmodels

I am thinking about a question regarding my business modelling. Let's say, I have a dataset as I shown in below:

```
data <- tribble(
  ~book, ~ranking_unique, ~ranking_rare, ~ranking_clicks, 
   "A",         2,              1,              4,
   "B",         1,              4,              1,
   "C",         5,              3,              2, 
   "D",         3,              5,              5, 
   "E",         4,              2,              3,
)
```

There are many books in the book column. Ranking_unique ranks the products based on how unique this book is. Namely, how many bookseller are selling this book or ranking_clicks means how many clicks we get for this book.

Now, I want to build a model to make a list that shows us the most valuable books. I was thinking  to cluster the books based on these ranking. But I could not find the ideal way to do it.

How would you approach this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are asking for modeling advice, this is the wrong place to do it. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. If you need help with statistical questions, you should ask at [stats.se] instead.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a hierarchical cluster analysis can be of value.

Link to documentation: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/hierarchical-cluster-analysis

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It was very helpful.